# Incorrect names appearing on images loaded in collectionview

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

This is my `json` response...

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "TotalRevenue": “123.12 K",
    "Productdata": [
        {
            "product_id": "5",
            "product_name": “abc”
            "product_images": [
                {
                    "id": "938",
                    "image_url": "http://myApp.direct.com/public165_1_image_15",
                    "is_default": "1"
                }

            ]
        }
```

And this is how I have parsed this data...

```
 if let projectData = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]] {

 let images = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_images"] as? [[String: Any]] }).flatMap({ $0 })

let productName = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_name"] as? String })
self.arrayOfNames = productName
self.arrayOfId = imageIds

}
```

I have extracted the names and assigned them to an array above(id and imageurl have also been extracted. But let us just consider name extraction for now.)

Then I take out each name from the array containing all the names like so...

```
                            for names in self.arrayOfNames {
                                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
                                    {
                                        self.theNameArray.append(names)

                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                        }
                                }
                            }
```

Finally, so that I can get the appropriate name under each image in the colletionview, I am doing this...

```
cell.recipeImageView.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = self.arrayOfNames[indexPath.row]
```

In the above 2 lines of code, the first one shows the images. But my issue is the names are not displayed appropriately i.e. the appropriate name for the image is not shown...instead any random name is assigned to any image. How can I get the correct name under the correct image.

I did go through posts which dealt with similar issues..but couldn't figure out a fix for my issue..It's simple I know...dealing just with key-value pairs but I'm not able to figure out exactly how...

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: What is the issue? I mean What problem you have in parsing?

Comment: @dahiya_boy the problem is this..Some images are loaded in the collectionview from url's. And each of these images has a name associated with it below. But I'm getting random names(incorrect names) under each image and not the correct name as per the json response...

Comment: Giving the correct key-value pairs maybe...but how exactly that can be done in this case...I can't figure out...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make dummy make sure it is proper, if there any issue you found then let me know

**ProductData**

```
var productData : [[String : Any]] = [["id" : "1",
                                       "name" : "a",
                                       "images" : [[
                                                    "id" : "11",
                                                    "url" : "url_a"]
                                                   ]
                                        ],
                                      ["id" : "2",
                                       "name" : "b",
                                       "images" : [[
                                                    "id" : "22",
                                                    "url" : "url_b"]
                                                   ]
    ]
]
```

Output of this array is like this

[image]

**Now parsing**

```
let images = productData.flatMap({ $0["images"] as? [[String: Any]] }).flatMap({ $0 })

let imageIds = images.flatMap({ $0["id"] as? String })
let productName = productData.flatMap({ $0["name"] as? String })
let productURL = images.flatMap({ $0["url"] as? String })
print(productURL)// output 1

print(productName)//output 2
```

**Parsing Output**

[image]

Url list and name list are in same order pls check.

Comment: Yes! you are correct, @dahiya_boy...while parsing even I got similar results..but my issue arises when I try to give (as per your case) the name 'a' to the image obtained from 'url_a'...

Comment: In other words, what I want to do is I want to assign name 'a' to 'url_a' and name 'b' to 'url_b'...

Comment: @User.bw it is independant, so always got correct result.